# PHP/MySQL update only when user clicks a button

Tags: php, html, mysql, onclick

Okay so, I'm having this bug with my login system, it says "Wrong username or password" when I just open the login.php page.

And I would like to know how do I make it so it checks my username and password only when I click the login button and not when I just load the page

My button is an `<input>` and I tried adding `onclick="checklogin()"`  and this was the checklogin function:

```
$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];

function checklogin()
{
    $sql="SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username`='". $username ."' and `password`='". md5($password) ."'";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);

    $count=mysql_num_rows($result);

    if($count==1){
        session_register("username");
        session_register("password"); 
        header("location:login_success.php");
    }else{
        echo "Wrong username or password.";
    }
}
```

But nothing happens... Page just refreshes even if  I get password/name right and even if I get it wrong... But when  I remove the "function checklogin()" (its content still remains, just removing the function tag) and the onclick attribute it will work but as I said in the beggining, it will say "Wrong password or username" when I just loaded up the page

So to make this shorter how do I make it so this login check is only applied when the user clicks the button (`<input type="submit" name="submit" value="login"/>`)

Comment: PHP = server side. JS = client side. the PHP will be parsed and won't be available after the page loads so your `onclick` is looking for a JS function. I'd recommend AJAX if you want a no refresh solution.

Comment: Sorry, I am still learning. I began learning 3 days ago... Still lots to learn. Thanks for the tip

Comment: Please don't use the original PHP MySQL API. Instead, consider switching to either MySQLi or PDO (PHP Data Objects)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `isset`

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];
}
```

Comment: I'm glad it worked. you should also check for empty field and alert the user to enter it. Appreciate it if u accept this answer.

Comment: Yeah gonna do it now, I had to wait. Thanks a lot again, and btw, I checked for empty field. :)

Answer (score 0):

Check that the $_POST array contains data:

```
function checklogin()
{
    if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_POST['submit'])) {

    $username=$_POST['username'];
    $password=$_POST['password'];

    $sql="SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username`='". $username ."' and `password`='". md5($password) ."'";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);

    $count=mysql_num_rows($result);

    if($count==1){
        session_register("username");
        session_register("password"); 
        header("location:login_success.php");
    }else{
        echo "Wrong username or password.";
    }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems here:

First one, function checklogin can't reach $password and $username, because it's creating new scope, you can use global:

```
function checklogin() {
global $password;
global $username;
// ...
```

Although I don't advice...

onClick event is for JavaScript, you cannot use PHP function from JavaScript.

You need to use AJAX here, to get the data from PHP and then update.